# Pandas calculate last few months data in new column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, multiple-columns

I have dataframe in the following format;

```
ID | 01/01/2016 | 02/03/2016 | 02/15/2016 | ........
11 | 100        | 200        | 100        | ........
```

I am trying to calculate the sum of e.g.: last 3 months data in the new column. Expected output should be as follows;

```
ID | 01/01/2016 | 02/03/2016 | 02/15/2016 | ........ | Last 3 Months
11 | 100        | 200        | 100        | ........ | 300
```

As a solution, I need to pick today's date and compare it with the dates in the column and sum up the values. However, I am not sure how to do that? Could you please give some tips?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as straight forward as it may initially seem.  You need to determine how you will handle year-to-year changes and having differing number of days in each month.  I do this using a simple function.  You can adjust the code below to meet your needs, but it should get you started.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

def subtract_months(m):
    '''subtracts specified number of months from current date

    Parameters
    ----------
    m : integer
        how many months to subtract from today's date

    Returns
    -------
    date : datetime value'''

    yr  = dt.date.today().year
    mon = dt.date.today().month - m
    day = dt.date.today().day


    # test whether we went into another year
    if mon<=0:
        yr  -=  1
        mon = 12 + mon


    # test whether we have exceeded maximum number of days in month
    if day>calendar.monthrange(yr,mon)[1]:
        day = calendar.monthrange(yr,mon)[1]

    return dt.date(yr,mon,day)





import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import calendar


dates = pd.date_range('20160101','20170101',freq='1D')
data  = pd.np.random.randint(0,100,(5,367))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=list('ABCDE'),columns=dates)

# now add a new column
df['Last 3 Months'] = df.T.truncate(before=subtract_months(3),after=dt.date.today()).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: This post helped me a lot! Great example. Thank you